# Options to replace Python F string

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, python-3.5, f-string

I'm trying to use YoutubeAPI to get the URLs from each video within a playlist. I found some code to help me do this, however, they use a print statement with an F string and a for loop that iterates over each video in the playlist. The problem is, I'm using python 3.5, when this came out in Python 3.6, so I was wondering how I may be able to get around this.

`print([  f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={t["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"]}&list={playlist_id}&t=0s' for t in playlist_items ])`

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
for t in playlist_items:
    print('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}&list={}&t=0s'.format(t["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"], playlist_id))
```